# detect cell value in different excel sheets that contains different value using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

Based on the code below, I want this code to detect the word "Oranges", "Oranges1", "Oranges 2" etc but all I can do now is only to detect Oranges. It became more complicated for me when I want to detect the word Oranges1 & Oranges2 in the different excel sheet. I have try to change

If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Oranges " Then to
 If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Oranges & Oranges1 " Then

but this doesn't work. I want to perform calculations once this code can detect the cell name.

Is there any solution for me with this case?

**My Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Get the last row with text
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer, Total As Double
Total = 0

' Use LastRow in loop
For i = 1 To LastRow

  ' Check if cell has text "Oranges"
  If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Oranges " Then
      Dim Val1 As Double
      Dim Val2 As Double

      Val1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
      Val2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value

     ' Add value in column B to total
      Total = Val1 + Val2
      Dim sum As Double
      sum = Val1 + Val2
      Worksheets("Interface").Cells(i, 3) = "Total"
      Worksheets("Interface").Cells(i, 4).Value = sum    
  End If          
  Exit For
Next i
```

Comment: You could check if the Cell Value contains the Text Oranges:
`If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "Oranges", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `If`s with `Select Case`, it will allow you to add more scenarios in the future.

```
Select Case Cells(i, 1).Value
    Case "Oranges", "Oranges1", "Oranges 2"
        ' the rest of your coding goes here

End Select
```

Comment: @farahxx  have you read me answer and code above ? any feddback ?